# Find a continuous, real valued function without maximum and show that a set is compact in $\ell^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, compactness

I am working on following task:

Let
$$ \ell^1(\mathbb{R}) = \{ x=(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty : x_k \in \mathbb{R}, \|x\|=\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k| < \infty \}.$$
Fix $y \in \ell^1$ and define
$$ B=\{x \in \ell^1: \|x\|\leq1\}$$
and
$$ M = \{x\in \ell^1: |x_k|\leq |y_k|\}.$$

> Find a continuous, real valued function on $\ell^1$ that does not have a largest value on $B$ and show that $M$ is a compact subset of $\ell^1$.

My first thought was that such a function doesn't exist, since $B$ is compact and a continous function will take its minimum and maximum value. But then I recognized that that $\ell^1$ is an infinite dimensional space, so the closed unit ball doesn't have to be compact anymore.
Do you have some good idea to define such a function?

For the compactness of $M$ I thought about using the definition, that every sequence in $M$ has a convergent subsequence in $M$. If I take a sequence $x^n$ in $M$, then $|x^n_k| \leq |y_k|$ for every $k$ (coordinates) and $n$ (member of the sequence). But how can I construct a convergent subsequence out of $x^n$?

Some hints or solutions would be really helpful.

Comment: Define a functional $f$ such that $f(e_k) = k$. The second part follows from the totally bounded & complete characterisation.

Comment: Are you sure this function works? I think you mean with $e_k$ the element with an 1 at the $k$'th position and othwerwise 0. So for an arbitrary $x = (x_1,x_2,...)$ it holds that $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k x_k$. Linearity is clear. That this function doesn't take its maximum in $B$ is also clear for me, but why is it continuous/bounded?

Comment: It comes with a 200% money back guarantee. You need to do a little work, it doesn't have to be linear, it just needs to be continuous. Use bump functions defined on $B(e_k, {1 \over 2})$ for example.

Comment: (Note, it cannot be linear, continuous and unbounded.)